# Opening Fancybox from <a> but need 'beforeClose' option. Adding in option JS opens Fancybox Twice

Tags: fancybox

I have an application which uses Fancybox and calls it from 'a' tags as follows:

```
<a class="link" href="#" data-fancybox="" data-type="ajax" data-src="favourite_record.php" >Link</a>
```

Within 'favourite_record.php is a 'div' with ID 'modal-fvourite-record' which contains a 'form'.

I need the Fancybox to not close when the  within the Fancybox when the 'submit' button is clicked.

```
<button data-fancybox-close="" type="submit" id="f-submit-button" onclick="Save();">Save</button>
```

I've tried to handle this by adding the following JS code inside 'favourite_record.php':

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('#modal-favourite-record').fancybox({
            beforeClose: function(instance, current, e) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        function Save() {
            document.favourite_record.submit();
        }

    </script>
```

However when I open the Fancybox from the 'a' tag and click within the Fancybox, it opens a second Fancybox on top.

How can I specify the 'beforeClose' functionality without it opening a second Fancybox?

Comment: I've fixed this by removing 'data-fancybox' from the 'a' tag and calling .open using JS, passing 'beforeClose' that way.

Comment: I found this pen useful in showing how this can be done... https://codepen.io/suhomlineugene/pen/zawPVq